# Calculating PDF given a histogram

Tags: python, probability-density

I have a heavily right-skewed histogram and would like to calculate the probabilities for a range of Lifetimevalues (Area under the curve, the PDF). For instance, the probability that the Lifetime value is in (0-0.01)

Dataframe consisting of LTV calculated by cumulative revenue/ cumulative installs:

`df['LTV']` is

```
(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.208125,0.0558879,0.608348,0.212553,0.0865896,
 0.728542,0,0.609512,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.0801339,0.140657,0.0194118,0,0,0.0634682,
 0.339545,0.875902,0.8325,0.0260526,0.0711905,0.169894,0.202969,0.0761538,0,0.342055,
 0.42781,0,0,0.192115,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1.6473,0,0.232329,0,2.21329,0.748,0.0424286,
 0.455439,0.210282,5.56453,0.427959,0,0.352059,0,0,0.567059,0,0,0,0.384462,1.29476,
 0.0103125,0,0.0126923,1.03356,0,0,0.289785,0,0)
```

I have tried utilizing SKlearn's KernelDensity, however, after fitting it to the histogram it does not capture the over-represented 0s.

```
import gc
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity

def plot_prob_density(df_lunch, field, x_start, x_end):
    plt.figure(figsize = (10, 7))

    unit = 0
    x = np.linspace(df_lunch.min() - unit, df_lunch.max() + unit, 1000)[:, np.newaxis]

    # Plot the data using a normalized histogram
    plt.hist(df_lunch, bins=200, density=True, label='LTV', color='blue', alpha=0.2)
    
    # Do kernel density estimation
    kd_lunch = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=0.00187).fit(df_lunch) #0.00187
  

    # Plot the estimated densty
    kd_vals_lunch = np.exp(kd_lunch.score_samples(x))


    plt.plot(x, kd_vals_lunch, color='orange')
    
    plt.axvline(x=x_start,color='red',linestyle='dashed')
    plt.axvline(x=x_end,color='red',linestyle='dashed')

    # Show the plots
    plt.xlabel(field, fontsize=15)
    plt.ylabel('Probability Density', fontsize=15)
    plt.legend(fontsize=15)
    plt.show()
    gc.collect()
    return kd_lunch
kd_lunch = plot_prob_density(final_df['LTV'].values.reshape(-1,1), 'LTV', x_start=0, x_end=0.01)
```

Then finding the probabilities like this:

```
def get_probability(start_value, end_value, eval_points, kd):
    
    # Number of evaluation points 
    N = eval_points                                      
    step = (end_value - start_value) / (N - 1)  # Step size

    x = np.linspace(start_value, end_value, N)[:, np.newaxis]  # Generate values in the range
    kd_vals = np.exp(kd.score_samples(x))  # Get PDF values for each x
    probability = np.sum(kd_vals * step)  # Approximate the integral of the PDF
    return probability.round(4)


print('Probability of LTV 0-3  tips during LUNCH time: {}\n'
      .format(get_probability(start_value = 0, 
                              end_value = 0.01, 
                              eval_points = 100, 
                              kd = kd_lunch)))
```

However, this method does not yield the appropriate PDF values we were aiming for.
Any suggestions for alternative methods would be appreciated.

PLot:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code you have use for KDE using Sklearn? Also, if possible please share the data over which you are trying to fit the PDF, along with plots you are getting as incorrect outputs.

Comment: When asking questions for code that relies on data, it is important that a minimal example of the data is included in your question.  The easier you make it for *us* to copy and paste from your question (so that we can execute your code and test our solution) the more likely you'll get responses. - Please read [mre]. How many rows in `final_df`?

Comment: Are you asking why SKLearn's KernelDensity when used in your `plot_prob_density` function doesn't conform to the data/histogram? Are you asking whether your methodology is valid? - you haven't provided `plot_prob_density` so we don't know what `kd_lunch` is, we can only guess.

Comment: Post has been updated with complete code

Comment: Seems like you are looking for a mixed random variable which is a mix between continuous and discrete.

Comment: `it does not capture the over-represented 0s.` - can you explain that? The first value in `kd_vals_lunch` (`kd_vals_lunch[0]`) is very large, much larger than the other values, and the graph/plot represents that - one of the vertical lines obscures it but it is there. So it is unclear why you think `plot_prob_density` produces an insufficient graph.

Comment: `does not yield the appropriate PDF values we were aiming for` - what were you aiming for? Have you tried [numpy.histogram](https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) with `density=True`?

Comment: @wwii I added the graph as a reference. Based on the graph, I would like to capture the probability within the orange lines. Let's say its LTV in range 0.00 - 0.01. Doing it manually its around 60% of the values (rows less than or equal to LTV 0.01 / total rows in df). The KDE says 36%.

Answer (score 0):

I have used more or less similar script for my work, here is my script may be it will be helpful for you.

```
import gc
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
from scipy import stats
data1 = beta_95[0]

def plot_prob_density(data1, x_start, x_end):
    plt.figure(figsize = (4, 3.5))

    unit = 1.5
    x = np.linspace(-20, 20, 1000)[:, np.newaxis]

    # Plot the data using a normalized histogram
    plt.hist(data1, bins=np.linspace(-20,20,40), density=True, color='r', alpha=0.4)
    #plt.show

    # Do kernel density estimation
    kd_data1 = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=1.8).fit(data1)

    # Plot the estimated densty
    kd_vals_data1 = np.exp(kd_data1.score_samples(x))

    plt.plot(x, kd_vals_data1, color='r', label='$N_a$', linewidth = 2)
    
    plt.axvline(x=9.95,color='green',linestyle='dashed', linewidth = 2.0, label='$β_o$')
    plt.axvline(x=1.9,color='black',linestyle='dashed', linewidth = 2.0, label='$β_b$')
    
    plt.axvline(x=x_end,color='red',linestyle='dashed', linewidth = 2, label='$β_{95\%}$')

    # Show the plots
    plt.xlabel('Beta', fontsize=10)
    plt.ylabel('Probability Density', fontsize=10)
    plt.title('02 hours window', fontsize=12)
    plt.xlim(-20, 20)
    plt.ylim(0, 0.3)
    plt.yticks([0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]) 
    plt.legend(fontsize=12, loc='upper left', frameon=False)
    plt.show()
    gc.collect()
    return kd_data1

def get_probability(start_value, end_value, eval_points, kd):
    
    # Number of evaluation points 
    N = eval_points                                      
    step = (end_value - start_value) / (N - 1)  # Step size

    x = np.linspace(start_value, end_value, N)[:, np.newaxis]  # Generate values in the range
    kd_vals = np.exp(kd.score_samples(x))  # Get PDF values for each x
    probability = np.sum(kd_vals * step)  # Approximate the integral of the PDF
    return probability.round(4)

data1 = np.array(data1).reshape(-1, 1)

kd_data1 = plot_prob_density(data1, x_start=3.0, x_end=13)

print('Beta-95%: {}\n'
      .format(get_probability(start_value = -10, 
                              end_value = 13, 
                              eval_points = 1000, 
                              kd = kd_data1)))
```